# how to order products based on free or not angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am using angular ng repeat to display products (json feed ), I would like to sort/ order the products based on whether its free or not (json property 'free':true ), so that I can display the free one's first and purchasable after.

It would be nice it this coulb be achieve through orberBy.

Thanks in advance.

Ryan

Comment: What you are looking for, is filter. Example: ng-repeat="item in items | filter:someFilter"  while $scope.someFilter will return true / false depending on some condition or just item.free maybe in this case. Edit: sorry, missanderstood. You need orderBy, not filters, filters will only show some part of the items array...

Answer (score 1):

Since you are dealing with booleans here you need to use `orderBy` like so:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items | orderBy:'free':true">
```

Just having `orderBy: 'free'` alone won't work since it's a boolean, so here we are specifying to then order them looking for `true`. Voila.

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/mcpDESIGNS/DrEHR/)**

Comment: Hi Everyone, Thanks for your replies. Hi McpDesigns, thank you so much. You solution works like a charm. Thanks again.

Comment: Hi, Is it possible to order products by name/title ?. Basically what I want is to keep/ dispaly, suppose productA always on top, while rest products can follow in any order.

Comment: Honestly I would just remove productA from the repeater, and simply have a seperate section/model for it above this. Much much easier that way since they aren't connected anyway now.